# Using Linqpad for a simple query

Tags: c#, linq, linqpad

This works within visual studio:

```
PeliculasEntities db = new PeliculasEntities();
DetalleAlquiler detalleAlquiler = (DetalleAlquiler)db.DetalleAlquilers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == 1);

MessageBox.Show(detalleAlquiler.Alquiler.Cliente.Natural.Edad.ToString());
```

I want to retrive the same information inside of LinqPad. Any help?

When I run this I get an error: "DetalleAlquiler does not have a definition for aAquiler"

```
var detalle = DetalleAlquilers.Where(x => x.ID == 1);
var edad = detalle.Alquiler.Cliente.Natural.Edad.ToString();
```

What variable do I use to access the database?
[image]

Comment: Please format your code properly - you have been here long enough and asked enough questions to know how to do so.

Answer (score 6):

Change Language to C# Expression.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to call `FirstOrDefault()` on your first line so 'detalle' is an `IEnumerable<DetailleAlquiler>` and not a `DetailleAlquiler`

Try:

```
var detalle = DetalleAlquilers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == 1);
var edad = detalle.Alquiler.Cliente.Natural.Edad.ToString();
```

Which is actually what you had, originally, in VS.  (Don't forget to add `edad.Dump();` if you actually want to see the results)

Comment: And yes, what SLaks says is true.  The above query will not work until you set the language to C# Expression.